# Firebase - Database : How to restrict access to sub-levels of other trees according to users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am a bit stuck on my project.

I have a list of users which include the events allowed.
I have a list of events with users allowed.

I want to allow a user to get only the list of their events in "users".
And of course, I want the json sent to only include the the content of their events.

**See the Database**

[image]

**See the Rules**

[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to allow a user access (read/write ?) to a specific part of the your database/events.

According to the [Firebase Secure Your Data docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data), you can specify who gets what. 
If you want the current user to be able to see the data in an event, I think this rule should work :

```
  {
   "rules": {
        "events": {// allows read to /events
          "$eventID": {
            ".read": "data.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
            ".write": false
          }
        }
     }
   }
```

If you want the user to be able to edit the information as well, copy the rule from `.read` to `.write`.

As for sending the JSON of this event specifically, you need to do it with a db query to that specific node in the DB.

Comment: Thank you Freddy :)